# Get all the events occurred till now in an Application

Tags: java, events, event-handling, dom-events, zk

I need to know the events occurred in my web app, from the time it was loaded. Is there any way to get the events, The reason is I need to store those events is when ever user wants to go directly to result which he got after performing few actions, I can do PostEvent on series of events to reach that particular result, or is there any other way to do the same with out storing events?

Example:

```
User clicks on button1 -button1 is disabled,
User Click on button2 - button2 is disabled,
User clicks on button3 -button3 is disabled,
User Click on button4 - button4 is disabled,
```

Now user has performed 4 actions to get all the four button disable.
If user wants to reach the state when 1st 3 buttons I will do PostEvent of clicking 3 buttons for him.

Note Example is not exactly what I need. It's just for explanation purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no support for this in GWT, you have to do it yourself. Record every action/event you're interested in, possibly using the command pattern, and log all of them for later replay.

Answer (score 0):

In ZK , you could use Event Interceptor to log all event you need.

http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Configuration_Reference/zk.xml/The_listener_Element/The_org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.EventInterceptor_interface